# How do I implement a Drawer menu in my pages?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, drawer

I have a dart file as a 'MyDrawer' and I want to add this drawer menu to my dashboard page. Here is my code. I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
  child: ListView(
  
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  children: <Widget>[
    DrawerHeader(
      child: Text('Menu drawer'),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.home, size: 40,),
      title: Text('First item'),
      subtitle: Text("This is the 1st item"),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
      onTap: () {
      },
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Second item'),
      onTap: () {
      },
    ),
  ],
),
);}}
```

And I'm calling this drawer menu in my dashboard page. It's like that;

```
  class Dash extends StatefulWidget { ...

  class _DashState extends State<Dash> { ...
  
 @override
 void initState(){ ...

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
 drawer: MyDrawer(),
  body: Container(
  ... ),
```

Comment: You have to return a Drawer() from your drawer class.

Comment: where is your MyDrawer?

Comment: It's in lib folder but dashboard page and mydrawer page are in different folder.

Comment: if my answer does not work, let me know and i can further try to understand your problem

Comment: try also pasting the error you're getting

Comment: It doesn't give any errors. I moved drawermenu.dart to same lib folder where dashboard it is. I also added return to Drawer. @pedropimont  .

Answer (score 0):

Your drawer `MyDrawer` should be a `StatelessWidget` that returns a `Drawer`.

This is how you should do it:

```
class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Text('Menu drawer'),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.home, size: 40,),
          title: Text('First item'),
          subtitle: Text("This is the 1st item"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          onTap: () {
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Second item'),
          onTap: () {
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: My dashboard page is different. First code block you wrote, Is it for another page what I'm talking about. I mean, should I add dashboard class to my drawer.dart?

Comment: you can have them in separate files, you only need to import the files you're working with... can you edit your question to add more information so we can understand better? Also, your ide should give you a hint of the error.... in the console or maybe its highlighting the error

Comment: it doesnt seem to be anything wrong with your code... is the app running? are you correctly importing drawermenu.dart file into the Dash file?

Comment: Everything is working. I'm achieving dashboard page after firebase connection. And I can edit anything I want to add in dashboard. In debug console, there is no error. I don't really understand. Btw, thanks for helping

Comment: well im sorry i could not help, but thats strange. I know its obvious but you know you have to swipe from left to right (or add an appBar on the Dash Scaffold) for the drawer to appear right? good luck....

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to add an appbar. I definitely missed these details. Here is the updated version.

```
    class Dash extends StatefulWidget { ...

    class _DashState extends State<Dash> { ...

    @override
    void initState(){ ...

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     drawer: MyDrawer(),
    body: Container(
    ... ),
```